# how to have spacing html/css

Tags: html, css, spacing

i have an html/css code here, which will result to this one.see image below.
I would like to add another 3 columns under the first "Future Event" How can I do that? 
already posted the code: thanks
what would be the code for the spacing of paragraphs?
thanks
please see the image here:
http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/nc1xjrptgddvk1yxvnad.png

I would like to adjust the space of "Future Event" like I would like to have it a little bit at the top. 
Is that possible?

This is the code: 
please check the updated codes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/4/

I need to have a separator in between but

---

doesn't work:-(

Comment: Can we have some source HTML and CSS too? Or a live Example?

Comment: +1 for mouse-drawn arrows. Yo!

Comment: when you say "I would like to add this one here" you mean the white space?

Comment: im pretty sure thats not XHTML 1.0 transitional valid HTML

Comment: Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/

Comment: @Sotiris:no not the white space. the other 3 columns under neath. because the original template is only 3 so i want to have 6 but it should be underneath. is that possible?

Comment: @Kyle: wow, cool can i edit that from here? what do you call this tool?

Comment: @Andrew Bullock: not sure what's the difference of two, would that be better if i will use with XHTML?

Comment: @tinticute: it's called www.jsfiddle.net and you can edit it from there, use javascript frameworks and css. Just edit and hit run, click update to save a new version with a unique URL to paste here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the CSS:

```
   #content .secondary-heading{
   font-size:18px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#333;
font-style:normal;
font-family:Georgia;
text-align:left;
margin-bottom:150px;
    }
```

Which specifies:

`margin-bottom:150px;`

But in your HTML you have inline code for the second

`<h2 class="secondary heading">` which states:

`style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: normal;color: #333;
    font-style: normal;font-family: Georgia;text-align: 
    left;margin-bottom: 15px;"`.

Take this inline style out and it should behave as expected.

**EDIT**

In the CSS: change `margin-bottom:150px;` to `margin-bottom:15px;`after deleting the inline style.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Kyle: I actually hide that code, and I just wrote like this: 
<h2 class="secondary-heading">Future Event</h2>
<p2 class=".secondary-paragraph">Sed ut persp iciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque.</p2>

Comment: pls check this site for the image: 
http://www.freeuploadimages.org/images/nc1xjrptgddvk1yxvnad.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/1/ check that out, just delete the inline style in your h2 tag. Works here on Chrome.

Comment: thanks, when you say inline style, is it in the CSS or the HTML? 
because in the html, i actually commented it.:
This is what I have now:
<h2 class="secondary-heading">Future Event</h2> <p2 class=".secondary-paragraph">Sed ut persp iciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque.</p2>

Comment: In the HTML, weird if you commented it out, it should work. Try just flat out deleting it.

Comment: it is still the same although i deleted it. and I'm using Firefox 3.6.8

Comment: do I need to put this one: <p2 class=".secondary-paragraph"> i mean with a dot?

Comment: No, dots are only for inside the CSS file. All you wanted to do was to have more space between the "Future Events" header and the text underneath right?

Comment: shall i write it with "p2 class"?

Comment: no i want to have a little space between the "Future Event" and the "Text". I mean, the space should be normal because as you can see in the png the space is very big. And I don't want it.

Comment: @Kyle: thanks for this, i already tried this but the "Future Event" is quite far from above. How can I have it a little bit at the top

Comment: Add a code like: `margin-top: -20px;` change the pixel value so as it suits you :)

Comment: shall i add it still at .secondary-heading?

Comment: ok i did change it, and i think it works now ;-) i just need to add the 3 blocks underneath so that I have 6 all in all ;-)

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept the answer that serves you best :)

Comment: @Kyle:please see this updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/1/ i would like to have like a separator in between of my new 3 blocks but <hr/> doesn't work

Comment: That's not an updated version, it's my version I showed you before, when you click update, copy the URL from the address bar and paste it here :)

Comment: Instead of just having the `<hr />` wrap it in another row `<tr>
                 <td colspan="3">
                     
                    <hr/>
                 </td>`

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/7/

Comment: do u think i can change the color of the hr/

Comment: Yes, you'll have to select in in the CSS: `hr {background-color: #f00;}`.

Comment: hey thanks so much this is what i have now:http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/9/ 
i use the hr in IE but it can't be seen quite strange

Comment: this is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/10/
but if i change the color of the gray line, it didn't change

Comment: Hi, you have to add height for it to work in Webkit browsers and use color for IE http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/11/

Answer (score 1):

to duplicate the three blocks, in fact you must copy the row, the `tr` tag which include them.
I copy/paste you the code:

```
<tr>
        <td class="content threecol first" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4em; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 25%; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 0pt; padding-top: 20px; border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"><!--<h2 class="secondary-heading" 
      style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: normal;color: #333;font-style: 
      normal;font-family: Georgia;text-align: 
     left;margin-bottom: 15px;">Future Event</h2>-->

          <h2 class="secondary-heading">Future Event</h2>
          <p2 class=".secondary-paragraph"> Sed ut persp iciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque.</p2></td>
        <td class="content threecol" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4em; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 28%; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"><h2 class="secondary-heading" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-style: normal; font-family: Georgia; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 15px;">Future Event</h2>
          <p>Sed ut persp iciatis unde omnis iste 
            natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
            aperiam, eaque.</p></td>
        <td class="content threecol last" style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4em; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 28%; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; margin-right: 15px; border: 0pt none;"><p class="btn" style="text-align: center; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(45, 45, 45); border: 3px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);">&nbsp; </p>
          <p class="btn" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(45, 45, 45); border: 3px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);"> <a href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 26px; font-family: Georgia; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; display: block; padding: 20px 0pt;"> <img height="50" border="0" width="119" alt="" src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/86b4d752e397a2dbd09e3dd60/images/logowikima4.gif" style="text-align: center; display: block;"></a> </p>
          <p class="btn" style="text-align: center; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(45, 45, 45); border: 3px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);">&nbsp; </p>
          <p> Let us know if you are coming and if you have guests.</p>
      </td></tr>
```

In your code you will find the above code, just paste the same below it.

About spacing, you can modify it, giving `line-height` for `secondary-heading` class.

for example `.secondary-heading {line-height:1.4;}` , just modify it according to your needs.

Comment: @Sotiris:i added the line-height under .secondary-heading and also in the .secondary-paragraph. but it is still the same. the space is still very big.

Comment: space of what? in the first block there is a big space because you have add `secondary-heading` on h2. if you delete it, is same with the second block. If you talk for another space, just inform me.

Comment: i want it to be normal space between the "Future Event" and the start of the "Text". That's right, there is a big space, that is what I wanted to solve here i don't want that big space, i want to have a small space between the title "Future Event" and the "Text" so you mean I have to delete the secondary-heading or the secondary-paragraph?

Comment: well, I look at it, in fact there is no reason to delete `secondary-heading`. In your css you will find the following  `#content .secondary-heading{font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; color:#333; font-style:normal; font-family:Georgia; text-align:left; margin-bottom:150px;}`

just delete the `margin-bottom:150px;` and you are done :)

Comment: @Sotiris, yes it is thanks and I forgot to put the dot for the secondary-heading. So it should be ".secondary-heading"
the thing is it's quite far below. Can I move it a little bit at the top?

Comment: in your code you will find a `td` which represent a block with `style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4em; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); width: 25%; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 0pt; padding-top: 20px; border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);"`. You just need add `vertical-align: top;` in the inline style. This will move the content on the top of the div. Add this line in each td. - here and a modification of your live example http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/3/

Comment: @Sotiris:thanks I already did, and i think it works fine. Now I add the 3 blocks and I would like to add a separator between them and <hr/> doesn't work.
try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fMe/1/

Comment: in the inline style of every block,other words td, add `border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);`

Comment: do i need to add this to the new block only?

Comment: for every block you wish to have a line in the bottom.

Comment: I would like to adjust the border length

Comment: @Sotiris can you please explain to me what is this 204,204,204

Comment: are the values of red,green,blue to give color for the border line.  Please accept an answer (or upvote). If you have additional questions open new questions. Stackoverflow works in this way. Thanks